# Can't update/change Email Address with AMPScript API

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api, ampscript

I am making a custom preference center using AMPScript and landing pages.  Everything works fine except I can't change the subscriber's email address in the same manner I update, say, the first name.  It doesn't error out.  It simply doesn't update.  The is a feature of the stock preference center so I imagine this should be possible.

Here is some of the code:

```
/* UPDATE Attributes */

SET @subkey = @email_address

/* Create the subscriber's object */
    set @subscriber = CreateObject( "Subscriber" )
    SetObjectProperty( @subscriber, "EmailAddress", @subKey )
    SetObjectProperty( @subscriber, "SubscriberKey", @subKey )

    SET @rr2 = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
    SetObjectProperty(@rr2,"ObjectType","Subscriber")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "ID")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "EmailTypePreference")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "EmailAddress")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "SubscriberKey")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@rr2, "Properties", "Status") 

/* SET SUBSCRIBER's ATTRIBUTE */
    /* SET SUBSCRIBER's ATTRIBUTE */
        SET @att=CreateObject("Attribute")
        SetObjectProperty(@att,"Name","Email Address")
        SetObjectProperty(@att,"Value","email***@gmail.com")
        AddObjectArrayItem( @subscriber, "Attributes", @att)



/* Update SUBSCRIBER */
   var @createOpts, @saveOpt

/* Create the save option */
    set @saveOpt = CreateObject("SaveOption")
    SetObjectProperty( @saveOpt, "SaveAction", "UpdateAdd" )
    SetObjectProperty( @saveOpt, "PropertyName", "*" )

/* Specify the Update option */
    set @createOpts = CreateObject("CreateOptions")
    AddObjectArrayItem( @createOpts, "SaveOptions", @saveOpt )

/* Update the subscriber */
   set @createStatusCode = InvokeCreate( @subscriber, @createErrDesc, @createErrNo, @createOpts )

/* If we failed to create the subscriber, output the information as the top level error */
   if @createStatusCode != "OK" then
    SET @TheWorks = 'false'
   else
    SET @TheWorks = 'true'
   endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you have to set the ID property on the subscriber object, ie

```
SetObjectProperty( @subscriber, "ID", '12121212' )
```

You may need to do a retrieve to lookup this value(it looks like the code is partially there to do a retrieve).  This ID the unique, system-generated identifier for a subscriber so it will never change which is needed because email address does change.

Also, the following section isn't needed since the EmailAddress property has to be set on the Subscriber object directly, not within the Attributes.

```
/* SET SUBSCRIBER's ATTRIBUTE */
    /* SET SUBSCRIBER's ATTRIBUTE */
        SET @att=CreateObject("Attribute")
        SetObjectProperty(@att,"Name","Email Address")
        SetObjectProperty(@att,"Value","email***@gmail.com")
        AddObjectArrayItem( @subscriber, "Attributes", @att)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds crazy, but I'm not sure you can change the email address.  SubscriberKey does allow the email address to be changed, but if that's not enabled in your account, you can't.

What I've done in the past is:

1. retrieve the subscriber
2. update the subscriber status to `unsubscribed`
3. create a new subscriber using the attributes retrieved, but with a status of `active`

This will disconnect the subscriber from all of their prior activity, but it's the cleanest way I've found.